# IntelliJ Community & Ultimate editions both on the same computer

Tags: java, spring, windows, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I would love to know if anyone has encountered a problem while using both IntelliJ Editions on the same computer, in my case as soon as I installed the Ultimate Edition my USB Modem stopped working.

I was obliged to restore my system to a date prior to the installation of the Ultimate Edition and now my Modem is working normally again.

Should I uninstall the Community Edition and re-install the Ultimate one ? What do you guys think ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up uninstalling the Community Edition and re-installing the Ultimate one, and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with both, but didnt face any such issues so far.